# Seeking shapefile of forest cover in Paraguay?

Tags: environment, geospatial, south-america

I am looking for a shapefile of the remaining forest cover in Paraguay. I am struggling to find an up to date file. Is there anywhere that has this information open access?

Comment: For open data the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://www.globalforestwatch.org/country/PRY download shapefile

Comment: @Mapperz, it looks like you answered the question in this comment. Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

[USGS Land Cover Institute's datasets for South America](https://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php#sa)
[World Wildlife Fund's Eco-Regions Data](https://www.worldwildlife.org/biomes)
[Global Forest Watch Search Results for "Paraguay"](http://data.globalforestwatch.org/datasets?q=paraguay&sort_by=relevance)

Answer (score 0):

The University of Maryland hosts a regularly updated, very high-resolution (30m) inventory of global forests globally. It specifically tracks forest loss from year 2000 but total coverage is also available.

[Global Forest Change 2000–2017](https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.5.html)